# Hypernym for "interpolation" and "extrapolation"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

*Interpolation* typically means modeling the values of some curve inside the given data, and *extrapolation* — outside the given data. For example, if I know the temperature on Monday and Wednesday, and ask for what it was on Tuesday — this is interpolation. If I ask for what it was on Sunday before or Thursday after, it is extrapolation.

I am looking for a word that would encompass both. I thought of *modeling*, but is there perhaps something better?

Comment: Would 'estimation' work for you?  To mean, 'modeling' refers to whatever process you use to arrive at the interpolation, extrapolation or estimation?

Comment: .....predicting

Comment: @EdwinAshworth `prediction` has a connotation of dealing with the future -- this is trying to produce past data of reasonable shape

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin `estimation` has a close connection to what I want. the connotation is usually estimating a single quantity, -- I am working with an entire curve. I would upvote if you wrote it as an answer...

Comment: No (to the statement in your second clause) – it's predicting further points (representing ordered pairs) on a curve on the basis of data already to hand. Interpolation and extrapolation constitute informed guesswork based on trends deduced from data. You can't 'produce' data except by experimentation / observation. If I guess that my curve goes through (43, 126) say, that ordered pair is certainly not part of my data.

Comment: I can't add an answer because it's closed. But "Resampling" applies to both.

Comment: @AdamB It has nothing to do with resampling, just predicting based on a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"data fitting" or "curve fitting" - depending on the context.

Comment: +1, closest one so far. I thought there was a direct connector of the two words, i guess not...

Answer (score 7):

**Estimation** is defined at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation) thus:

> Estimation is the process of finding an estimate, or approximation, which is a value that is usable for some purpose even if input data may be incomplete, uncertain, or unstable. The value is nonetheless usable because it is derived from the best information available.

It was my first choice for an answer because it is used in science and engineering.

My second choice was **Approximation** but after reading the [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation) it seems to focus on the use of a simpler model as a substitute for a more complex model. I believe that amounts to the same thing as *estimation*.

Now, under the heading **Numerical analysis**, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) states

> The field of numerical analysis includes many sub-disciplines. Some of the major ones are ...
>   **Interpolation**, **extrapolation**, and **regression**

So perhaps *numerical analysis* is the best hypernym, even though it doesn't "sound" much like *interpolation* and *extrapolation*. On the other hand both *estimation* and *approximation* do "sound" right, both as headings or as actions.

Answer (score 4):

In either case, you're *approximating* the temperature, and are thus performing an *[approximation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/approximation)*.

Comment: Interesting alternative, but seems to miss a strong connotation from both words. Both `inter-` and `extrapolation` have a connotation of producing something unknown from something known, `approximation` does not necessarily. I did upvote, but it doesn't sound right in my context...

Comment: You may be thinking of _approximation_ in too narrow a sense. Note how _approximate_ is used to describe **both** interpolation and extrapolation in [this article](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/06LeastSquares/extrapolation/complete.html).

Answer (score 2):

For a single hypernym, I recommend **regression**.

[See Wikipedia article for more.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Interpolation_and_extrapolation)

Comment: Regression is only one kind of extrapolation or interpolation. I did not downvote, but this is totally not my intent when I was asking this.

Answer (score 2):

How about modeled, calculated, or predicted?

Comment: To leave a helpful answer, you should explain *why* you believe these words would be appropriate, with links to appropriate references. If you are new to the Stack Exchange model, I encourage you to visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for this word too.

We use `polation`. Yes it's made up. Yes i prefer it to all the alternatives offered here.

Answer (score 1):

"Projecting" could work for both.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the word `fitting`, which fits (pun intended) in both a point value sense and in a curve handling sense as well.

Comment: If that is the one that works for you, you should really "accept" Yiorgos' answer, and maybe transfer this answer to there as a comment. And maybe vote for my explanatory answer, too  :-)

Answer (score -1):

"Numerical Analysis" is probably the parent concept and therefore the best fit.

Comment: Doesn't fit well for me. Perhaps you can say one `numerically analyzes` a curve, but it is not commonly used except to indicate the general field to which such questions belong, not an action...

Answer (score -1):

Tough one. Perhaps "inference" ...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers are best when they are explained, and accompanied by appropriate examples and/or reference citations. We want the poster to understand *why* you think *inference* would be appropriate. The [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will have additional guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: Inference has strong links to statistics.