# If it's not extrapolation, interpolation or estimation, what is it?

Tags: single-word-requests

As a Vocational Evaluator, I'm tasked with producing grade-levels, based on another clinician's work.  He used the Woodcock-Johnson to produce standard scores, but he didn't include grade-levels.  I solve this problem by using the Wide-Range Achievement Test IV tables to convert SS to raw scores, which I then plug into the corresponding WRAT age-based grade-level tables, to get GL.  What can I call this process.  I don't like extrapolation, interpolation or estimation.  What else is there?

Comment: I'm tempted to call it *transformation*, but I didn't understand a thing you wrote.

Comment: It sounds to me like your converting one thing to another.  It's difficult to say anything more because your description is full of terms that presumably mean something to people in your field but not to me.

Comment: 'Working up' data is a hypernym from what I remember.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146171/hypernym-for-interpolation-and-extrapolation?rq=1

Comment: I would call this ***derivation***

Answer (score 0):

You determined the WRAT grade level after converting Woodcock-Johnson standardized scores to raw scores using WRAT IV tables.

This process can be described as *[back transformation](http://www.biostathandbook.com/transformation.html)*, *[data mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapping#Data-driven_mapping)*,  *[rescaling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rescaling)* or *recalibration*.